# How to map year of datetime column from another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe in the following format. The year is wrong in the Date column I want to be able to replace

```
   Date         Year
0  2013-04-13   2019
1  2013-04-13   2019
```

What's the best way of mapping the Year into the datetime column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
df.apply(lambda x :x.Date.replace(year=x.Year),1)
Out[307]: 
0   2019-04-13
1   2019-04-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.Date += pd.to_timedelta(df.Year - df.Date.dt.year, unit='Y')
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to call `dt.normalize()` at the end to get a date object back.

Comment: @cs95 you're right. Thanks. I'll leave the answer as it is though.